# What should be the architecture/design of a Java EE web application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

How do I architect a Java EE web application which is based on JSP, Struts 2, Spring 3 and hibernate?
What is the best way to design a starting framework for such web application?

The other technologies that will be used extensively in the application are DWR and jQuery.

Comment: And may I know why have you chosen those technologies? Ideally speaking architecture is supposed to be technology agnostic. So I am not sure how come you have chosen the technologies before and are now looking to architect the application? The way I was taught is come up with an architecture and choose the technologies that would help you realize that architecture!

Comment: +1 Nilesh: I am agree Technologies is decided after you have your requirements and flow decided..If u decided all these platform means you already know what to use where

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to design a web application using Spring, follow the points below exactly:

1. Use Dependency injection always. Never have any tier of you application dependent on any other tier.
2. Always code to interfaces and inject the actual implementation through DI. This is pretty much how you accomplish point #1.
3. Try to design your application in a RESTful way. Never ever make your View decide how the application works, this is a big problem I have seen in a lot of applications, especially with programmers who are doing there first project in spring, where ease of coding is given more impetus than to a good design.
4. Design your database schema properly, if you don't know what you are doing -> Ask for help. Trust me if you screw this up, you will be in a lot of trouble.
5. Know your concerns (what your application needs to address) beforehand and defined properly, this will help you define you transactions and data access layer.
6. Before you sit down and start hitting the keyboard, read about some design principles, the ones like DI, IoC, Factory, AOP, Listener-Publisher, etc.
7. Read the spring documentation carefully. Same applies to Hibernate or JPA.
8. Take a look at as many projects as you can get your hands on too.

May the Force be with you!!

Answer (score 3):

I have written a series of articles that specifically addresses these questions, especially architecture and design of Java EE applications. I will also present the source code. It is implemented with Spring MVC, Hibernate and MySql. But the ideas are quite general, can be applied with various technologies. I hope that helps you.
http://www.nazar-merza.com

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Spring Roo project, it creates a basic framework for you (scaffolding): http://www.springsource.org/roo

Comment: But using Spring Roo will make my application based on Spring ROO? We will be using spring mostly for Hibernate ORM and dependency injections.